# New line character in Scala

Tags: scala, newline

Is there a shorthand for a new line character in Scala? In Java (on Windows) I usually just use "\n", but that doesn't seem to work in Scala - specifically

```
val s = """abcd
efg"""
val s2 = s.replace("\n", "")
println(s2)
```

outputs

```
abcd
efg
```

in Eclipse,

```
efgd
```

(sic) from the command line, and

```
abcdefg
```

from the REPL (GREAT SUCCESS!)

`String.format("%n")` works, but is there anything shorter?

Comment: I tried "\n" at the scala command line (2.9.0):
scala> "\n"
res0: java.lang.String = 
"
"
So it seems to work in this case.

Comment: @Owen yes the REPL seems to work OK, I meant running the .class from the command line as opposed to the Eclipse console

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your Eclipse making the newline marker the standard Windows \r\n, so you've got "abcd\r\nefg".  The regex is turning it into "abcd\refg" and Eclipse console is treaing the \r slightly differently from how the windows shell does.  The REPL is just using \n as the new line marker so it works as expected.

Solution 1: change Eclipse to just use \n newlines.

Solution 2: don't use triple quoted strings when you need to control newlines, use single quotes and explicit \n characters.

Solution 3: use a more sophisticated regex to replace \r\n, \n, or \r

Comment: 3.1 Actually, `replace` doesn't take regex, `replaceAll` does. 3.2 Furthermore, `"\n"` isn't regex newline, it is Java new-line in the string. The regex newline must be written as `"\\n"` or `"""\n"""`.

Comment: Solution 1 didn't work when I tried it. @Daniel, I know what you mean, but AFAIK there's no special character in regex to represent a newline. Hence `replaceAll("\\n", "")` doesn't work either

Comment: Did no one mention s.lines.mkString?  Use line-oriented functions to avoid dealing with newlines.

Answer (score 32):

A platform-specific line separator is returned by

```
sys.props("line.separator")
```

This will give you either "\n" or "\r\n", depending on your platform.  You can wrap that in a val as terse as you please, but of course you can't embed it in a string literal.

If you're reading text that's not following the rules for your platform, this obviously won't help.

References:

- [scala.sys package scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.sys.package)  (for sys.props)
- [java.lang.System.getProperties javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29) (for "line.separator")

Comment: Also with java 7 you can use `System.lineSeparator()`

Answer (score 9):

Try this interesting construction :)

```
import scala.compat.Platform.EOL
println("aaa"+EOL+"bbb")
```

Comment: It's commposition of other replies with a instant solution embedded in scala. Details can be found in Scala API

Answer (score 8):

If you're sure the file's line separator in the one, used in this OS, you should do the following:

```
s.replaceAll(System.lineSeparator, "")
```

Elsewhere your regex should detect the following newline sequences: "\n" (Linux), "\r" (Mac), "\r\n" (Windows):

```
s.replaceAll("(\r\n)|\r|\n", "")
```

The second one is shorter and, I think, is more correct.

Answer (score 5):

```
var s = """abcd
efg""".stripMargin.replaceAll("[\n\r]","")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\r\n` instead

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

Comment: Thanks. Would it stop someone compiling the file in Unix though?